# How To Query To Check For Different Values in One Column Against 2 Adjacent Dates?

Tags: sql, db2

OK, so what I'm trying to do is find out if an employee of a company has a certain value attached to them on Day 1 and another on Day 2. I've tried using a subquery to find an employee with the first value, and then query as normal for the 2nd, but zero results come in, and I have to change the date values each time I run it.

I guess what I want to do is search within a date range, and if the value is found somehow check the next date for the other value.

Here is what I have so far.

```
SELECT  employee ID, dateWorked, timeSummary 
WHERE employee_= (SELECT employeeID FROM worked_summ
WHERE date(date_worked) = '2019-11-02'
AND timeSummary like ('%PTO%')
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW only)
And date(date_worked) = '2019-11-03'
AND timeSummary like ('%shift_missed%');
```

Comment: Provide sample data and the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using LEAD

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
        employeeID
    ,   dateWorked
    ,   timeSummary 
    ,   LEAD(timeSummary) OVER( PARTITION BY employeeID ORDER BY dateWorked) 
            as Next_timeSummary
    FROM
        worked_summ
)
WHERE
    date(date_worked) = '2019-11-02'
AND timeSummary like ('%shift_missed%')
```